# Fake a locale field for model testing

Tags: python, django, testing, faker

I simply have a collection of languages in a model like this:

```py
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES

class AvailableLanguage(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGES, unique=True)
```

In `factories.py`, I'd like to fake `code` field. I've tried to pick up a locale code ramdomly from `LANGUAGES` but it fails. Instead of creating one instance of `AvailableLanguage`, it loops over languages and quickly raises an issue because `code` is set to `unique`.

So I thought of creating a Provider as a singleton, and it fails for the same reason. It generates all the locale codes instead of providing only one !

```py
class Provider(BaseProvider):

    lang_code = NotImplemented

    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.langs = LANGUAGES
        self.generator = generator

    def __getattribute__(self, attrib):
        if attrib == 'lang_code':
            self.lang_code = self.langs.pop()[0]
            return self.lang_code
        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(attrib)


fake.add_provider(Provider)


class AvailableLanguageFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    code = Faker('lang_code')

    class Meta:
        model = AvailableLanguage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Iterator](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#iterator)
from factory boy.

```py
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES
import factory


class AvailableLanguageFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    code = factory.Iterator(LANGUAGES, getter=lambda l: l[0])

    class Meta:
        model = AvailableLanguage
```